# SQL Statement, always list 3 entries of a sort

Tags: php, mysql

I have another Problem

I just can show you this on an example:

I got a Table called "myTable" with 7 entries

```
myTable | id | user_id |
           1      1 
           2      1
           3      1
           4      1 
           5      2
           6      2 
           7      2  
           8      2  
           9      2  
           10     2
```

Now i want to list just 3 entries of any user_id, but i cant find out myself how to.

Please help!

------- EDIT

My result have to look like this:

```
id=1 | user_id=1
id=2 | user_id=1
id=3 | user_id=1
id=5 | user_id=2
id=6 | user_id=2
id=7 | user_id=2
```

Comment: Any preference for which 3 entries are returned (e.g., the three smallest id's, the three largest id's)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from table as t1
where (select count(*) from table as t2
       where t1.user_id = t2.user_id and t2.id < t1.id) <3
```

Comment: i am back, it works. thank you very much! greetings from germany

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY ...
LIMIT 3
```

The LIMIT clause takes two arguments: number of rows to return, and an offset if you want to display something other than the first X rows. Details [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) in the MySQL docs.

Comment: this shows me just 3 entries, i want 3 entries of any user_id in the list.... in this example i want 3 entries of user_id=1 and 3 entries of user_id=2

Comment: You should rephrase your question then. "3 entries from EACH user". You just said "3 entries of any user.".

Answer (score 0):

If you want only 3 rows, you can use `limit` :

```
select * from myTable limit 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 3
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html